# Regular expression hex bytes in string

Tags: regex, string, qt, hex, byte

I am trying to validate the input of a LineEdit widget in Qt. I am using regular expressions for the first time so I could use some help. I want to allow 1 to 32 hex bytes separated by a space, for example this should be valid:

```
"0a 45 bc 78 e2 34 71 af"
```

And here are some examples of invalid input:

`"1 34 bc 4e"` -> They need to be written in pairs, so 1 must be 01.

`"8a cb3 58 11"` -> cb3 invalid.

`"56 f2 a8 69 "` -> No trailing space is allowed.

After some head scratching I came up with this regex which seems to work:

```
"([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[ ]){0,31}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})"
```

Now on to my questions:

1. Do you see any problems with my regex that my tests have failed to show? If so how can I improve it?
2. Is there a cleaner way to write it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Minor optimisation: use the case-insensitive flag. Otherwise, great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what method you used for validation, but one possible problem is that the method searches the string for substring that matches the pattern rather than checking the string matches the pattern. Use [`exactMatch`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qregexp.html#exactMatch) for validate a string against a regular expression.

In any case, adding anchors `^` and `$` is safer (not necessary when `exactMatch` is used, though):

```
"^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[ ]){0,31}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$"
```

Since you are doing validation, you don't need capturing. And you don't need to put space in `[]`

```
"^(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2} ){0,31}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}$"
```

You can set case-sensitivity with [`setCaseSensitivity`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qregexp.html#setCaseSensitivity) method. If you set it to `Qt::CaseInsensitive`, you can shorten the regex a bit:

```
"^(?:[0-9a-f]{2} ){0,31}[0-9a-f]{2}$"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I only use the `setValidator` method of the `QLineEdit` widget, I don't know what is used internally for the actual matching.

Comment: @dbostream: If you pass in `QRegExpValidator`, then it will most probably use `exactMatch` internally (inferred from description of how `QRegExpValidator` works: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qregexpvalidator.html#details)

Comment: Yes that is how I am doing it. Thanks